# Write type guard which narrows type T to Array<K>

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a javascript function which checks if any input value is Array:

```
function isArray<T, K>(value: T): value is Array<K> {
    return Array.isArray(value);
}
```

How would I correctly convert it to typescript  generic type guard, so it can accepts any value and returns some Array?

Finally I want Typescript to understand this code:

```
...
if (isArray(style)) {
  // here Typescript understands style is Array<TextStyle>
  for (const textStyle of style) {
    if (hasDefinedProperty(textStyle, "lineHeight")) lineHeight = textStyle.lineHeight;
    if (hasDefinedProperty(textStyle, "fontSize")) fontSize = textStyle.fontSize;
  }
  if (typeof lineHeight !== 'undefined') style.push({ lineHeight })
}
```

Comment: Type guard is for narrowing the type. You cannot narrow to generic K, K needs to be something more specific. Type guards are tools to get to final type. You can narrow to Array<X> but X needs to be some specific type. Consider:
`function isArray(value: unknown): value is Array<unknown> {
    return Array.isArray(value);
}
function isStrArray(value: Array<unknown>): value is Array<string> {
  return typeof value[0] === 'string'
}`

Comment: What is the declared type of `style` in your example code?  And when you say "TypeScript understands `style` is `Array<TextStyle>`", what is the `TextStyle` type?  Right now this doesn't seem to be a [mcve].  Depending on your definitions, you can just use `if (Array.isArray(style)) {...}` and it'll work.  If not, then we need more info.  Good luck!